# Where to put the .cargo/config.toml file in a cargo workspace?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

It's stated in the Cargo Book (on page [3.6. Configuration](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html)) that when `cargo` is invoked from the workspace root, the `.cargo/config.toml` files specified for individual packages within the workspace do not get read.

> At present, when being invoked from a workspace, Cargo does not read config files from crates within the workspace. i.e. if a workspace has two crates in it, named `/projects/foo/bar/baz/mylib` and `/projects/foo/bar/baz/mybin`, and there are Cargo configs at `/projects/foo/bar/baz/mylib/.cargo/config.toml` and `/projects/foo/bar/baz/mybin/.cargo/config.toml`, Cargo does not read those configuration files if it is invoked from the workspace root (`/projects/foo/bar/baz/`).

Also, it's not exactly specified either in [14.3. Cargo Workspaces - The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html) or [3.6. Configuration - The Cargo Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) where to put a `.cargo/config.toml` that would be common to all the packages in the workspace.

My objective here is to specify a single folder where all packages in the workspace should look for the vendored code of external dependencies.

Like if `path/to/workspace/root` is the the workspace root folder, the packages in the workspace should look for vendored external dependencies in `path/to/workspace/root/vendoredcode`.

For a single package outside of a workspace, I'd put it `.cargo/config.toml` in the package root and put the following in it:

```ini
[source.crates-io]
replace-with="vendored-sources"

[source.vendored-sources]
directory="path/to/package/root/vendoredcode"
```

How to do the same for all packages in a workspace with a single `.cargo/config.toml` file?

**PS**:
There might be some confusion due to my consistent use of the term "package" where some people might commonly use the term "crate".

I read that a single package (a folder with `Cargo.toml` and an `src` subfolder which contains `main.rs` and/or `lib.rs`) can actually contain multiple binary crates and a single library crate at the same time, so I preferred to use the term "package" instead of "crate" for it.

This choice was to avoid confusion though I recognise that while it might avoid confusion with one set of people, it might create confusion with another set of people. Hence this clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `.cargo/config.toml` at the root of the workspace.